# How to handle apostrophe when binding to hidden field in Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I've got a gridview with a hidden field, and I'm trying to set a value as follows:

```
<div class="newsletter" 
     onclick="document.getElementById('divMail').style.display='block';
              document.getElementById('hdnTitleOfContent').value='<%# Eval("mailTitle") %>';">
</div>
```

It works fine, but when I have an apostrophe sign in `mailTitle` like "how's etc" then it blocks my other code.

How can I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `'` with `&#39;` in the string for your title.

Comment: As per your info now am using code as :

  <div class="newsletter" onclick="document.getElementById('divMail').style.display='block';document.getElementById('hdnTitleOfContent').value='<%# Title(Eval("mailTitle").ToString())%>';"></div>    

Here i am calling server side Title method to implement replace.Which work fine but click event still blocked by apostrophe sign.This is title example given below :

<div class="newsletter" onclick="document.getElementById('divMail').style.display='block';document.getElementById('hdnTitleOfContent').value='Who's this man';"></div>

Comment: Just apply the same principle to you're onclick event and you should be fine.